# Set Pytest mock value to None

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a **main.py** file which includes **WindoMgr** class, **xvfb** as a class attibute and two **classmethods**: **_cleanup_lock_file** and **func_to_test**. I only have problem with testing **else** block, which gets triggered when **cls.xvfb** is **None**. The else block returns default value of **b** which is 1.

```
#main.py
class WindowMgr:
    xvfb = None

    @classmethod
    def _cleanup_lock_file(cls):
        return True

    @classmethod
    def func_to_test(cls):
        b = 1
        if cls.xvfb is not None:
            print(cls.xvfb)  #<MagicMock name='xvfb' id='61908568'>
            try:
                cls.xvfb.terminate()
                b = 2
            except Exception:
                b = 1 + 2
            finally:
                cls._cleanup_lock_file()
        else:
            return b
        return b
```

Now, in the **test_main.py** file, I have patched the `xvfb` to mock `cls.xvfb.terminate()` in try block, but I want `cls.xvfb` to be **None** for the **else** block to be triggered. I have tried something like `xvfb = None` or `xvfb.return_value = None`. But the else block doesn't get triggered as printing `cls.xvfb` shows it as a `MagickMock` object as commented out in the code. The `WindowMgr.func_to_test()` return value is 2 and not 1. It should return default value of b as 1.
How do I set `cls.xvfb` mock object as `None`? Any help would be appreciated.

```
#test_main.py
from main import WindowMgr

def test_main_func(mocker):
    xvfb = mocker.patch.object(WindowMgr, 'xvfb')

    # To test the else block
    # xvfb = None -----> doesn't work
    # xvfb.return_value = None ----> doesn't work

    assert WindowMgr.func_to_test() == 1   # AssertionError: assert 2 == 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that setting `xvbf` does only reassign the local variable, not the mocked variable (this is just normal Python behavior). Setting the `return_value` does not work, because `xvbf` is not a callable. However, if you use a [property mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) instead of a regular mock, it will behave as if it were a callable, and the value can be set via `return_value`:

```py
def test_main_func(mocker):
    xvfb = mocker.patch.object(WindowMgr, "xvfb",
                               new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock)
    xvfb.return_value = None

    assert WindowMgr.func_to_test() == 1
```

(you can access `PropertyMock` directly from `mocker` as a convenience)

Even if `xvbf` is a class variable and not a property, it behaves like a property from the perspective of a mock and this will work.